# Unable to make predictions due to incompatible matrix shape/size

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to make a model to predict insurance cost based on the individual. And this is the code for it.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from LSR import ListSearchReplace as LSR

csv = pd.read_csv("main.csv")
partialInputs = csv[["age", "bmi", "children"]]
smoker, sex = list(csv["smoker"]), list(csv["sex"])

L1 = LSR(smoker)
L1.replace("yes", 1, True)
L1.replace("no", 0, True)

L2 = LSR(sex)
L2.replace("female", 1, True)
L2.replace("male", 0, True)

pdReadySmoker = pd.DataFrame({"smoker": smoker})
pdReadySex = pd.DataFrame({"sex": sex})

SmokerAndSex = pd.merge(pdReadySmoker, pdReadySex, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)

INPUTS = pd.merge(partialInputs, SmokerAndSex, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
TARGETS = csv["charges"]

INPUTS = torch.from_numpy(np.array(INPUTS, dtype='float32'))
TARGETS = torch.from_numpy(np.array(TARGETS, dtype='float32'))

print(INPUTS.shape, TARGETS.shape)

loss_fn = F.mse_loss
model = nn.Linear(5, 3) # <-- changing this, changes the error message.
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

trainDataset = TensorDataset(INPUTS, TARGETS)
BATCH_SIZE = 5
trainDataloader = DataLoader(trainDataset, BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

def fit(numEpochs, model, loss_fn, opt, trainDataloader):
    for epochs in range(numEpochs):
        for inputBatch, targetBatch in trainDataloader:
            preds = model(inputBatch)
            loss = loss_fn(preds, targetBatch)
            loss.backward()
            
            opt.step()
            
            opt.zero_grad()
        
        e = epoch + 1
        if e % 10 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch: {e/numEpochs}, loss: {loss.item():.4f}")

fit(100, model, loss_fn, opt, trainDataloader) <-- error
```

Error produced:

```
<ipython-input-7-b7028a3d94fd>:5: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([5])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([5, 3])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  loss = loss_fn(preds, targetBatch)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d8f5bcdc847d> in <module>
----> 1 fit(100, model, loss_fn, opt, trainDataloader)

<ipython-input-7-b7028a3d94fd> in fit(numEpochs, model, loss_fn, opt, trainDataloader)
      3         for inputBatch, targetBatch in trainDataloader:
      4             preds = model(inputBatch)
----> 5             loss = loss_fn(preds, targetBatch)
      6             loss.backward()
      7 

D:\coding\machine-learning\env-ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   2657         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
   2658 
-> 2659     expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
   2660     return torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))
   2661 

D:\coding\machine-learning\env-ml\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py in broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
     69         if any(type(t) is not Tensor for t in tensors) and has_torch_function(tensors):
     70             return handle_torch_function(broadcast_tensors, tensors, *tensors)
---> 71     return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)  # type: ignore
     72 
     73 

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (5) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I've tried changing the dimensions of the of model, and these are a few of the changes made and the associated errors:

```
model = nn.Linear(5, 1338)

Error:
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1338) must match the size of tensor b (5) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

```
model = nn.Linear(1338, 1338)

Error:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (5x5 and 1338x1338)
```

Sometimes this error, will make me change the matrix to the correct shape, but that results in the previous error regarding `non-singleton dimension`

Comment: Your output shape (defined by the number of neurons on the your last layer) must be the same as the target shape. I'm guessing your targets are `(-1, 5)`?

Comment: What does the -1 mean? The targets are just (1338).

Comment: The `-1` refers to the batch size. What is the shape of `TARGETS` ?

Comment: the batch size is 5 and the shape of `TARGETS` is `torch.Size([1338])`

Comment: So to summarize; can you change really quick to model = nn.Linear(5, 5) and run it?

Comment: Making the changes, it gave [this](https://paste.rs/MsM) error. @GaussianPrior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite straight-forward, you only have a single layer. This is a matter of sorting the shapes right.

You are feeding a [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) layer an input with shape `input_shape`. This type of layer takes two arguments: `in_features` the number of features in the input vector, and `out_features` the number of features in the resulting vector. Since you are using the [`F.mse_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html), your target vector needs to have the same shape as your prediction.

Bear in mind the first dimension is the batch dimension. In summary, your input tensor has shape `(batch, input_size)`, your dense layer is defined as `nn.Linear(input_size, out_size)` and your target tensor has shape `(batch, output_size)`.

---

Coming back to your case, your `TARGETS` tensor is of shape `(1338)` so you either mean to:

- have a single prediction with `1338` components which would match a `nn.Linear(?, 1338)` and it would actually correspond to `(1, 1338)` (a single element in the batch). This can be fixed with `TARGETS = TARGETS.unsqueeeze(0)`.
- or, there are actually `1338` predictions one element, which would match a `nn.Linear(?, 1)` and the appropriate target shape would be `(1338, 1)`. This can be fixed with `TARGETS = TARGETS.unsqueeeze(-1)` (adds an additional axis after the last dimension).

Comment: Sorry but could you rewrite your answer in simpler English? Because english isn't my first language,

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are trying to say in your first bullet point, but, there are 1338 predictions/values in a single matrix.

Comment: Then your case corresponds to the 2nd bullet point where you have 1338 predictions containing 1 value each.

Comment: "I have edited my answer, does it help?"  
Yeah it does

Comment: But could you explain what "adds an additional axis after the last dimension" means? Is it say you have `a = [1, 2]` then it adds another axis right after 2?

Comment: `[1,2]` would have a shape of `(2)`, so adding an additional axis would result in a shape of `(2, 1)` (here `dim0=2` and `dim1=1`) and for this tensor would be `[[1],[2]]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226655/discussion-between-dexyap-and-ivan).

Answer (score 1):

Your input dimension is 5, and you predict a scalar value (`target`) for each input.
Therefore, your linear model should be of size:

```py
model = nn.Linear(5, 1)  # from 5-dim inputs to 1-dim output
```

I think the setting batch size to 5 (similar to input dimension) is confusing you. Try changing the batch size and see how it does not affect the dimensions of the model.

Comment: I've changed the batch size from 5, to 10, to 1. The code runs but there are [user warnings](https://paste.rs/EYL) (this is when the batch size is set to 1) that are still produced.

Comment: @DexYap for batch size = 1 the user warning basically tels you to pay attention to the sizes. You are okay and can ignore this warning.